# How to buy more RAM without CPU?

Tags: ram, cpu, chintai

Currently I am running low on CPU and would love to borrow some from Chintai but it says I have to little RAM to be able to complete the transaction (which is true, I am running very low). However, in order for me to be able to buy more RAM it says I need more CPU because I have none.

Does anyone have any ideas how to solve this chicken and egg problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: cpu emergency service? https://www.eosrp.io/

Comment: That's what I was thinking at first too @confused00 but looks like under current network conditions I need to stake more eos for them to lend me some in the short term. And sadly to be able to stake more eos you need at least a little cpu on hand :(

Answer (score 1):

I think it makes sense to have more than one EOS account, exactly to deal with this case. In your "emergency" account, you have EOS that you are to use only for staking as needed. Either you can stake to yourself directly, or if this wouldn't be enough, you can buy a larger stake through Chintai, and delegate it to your main account.